# Matching in list of vectors with differents lengths

Tags: r, list, match

I have two lists like that :

```
List1 <- list(c("toto", "titi"), c("tata"), c("toto", "tz", "tutu"))

List2 <- list(c("titi", "toto", "tutu"),
              c("tata", "trtr", "to", "tututu"),
              c("to", "titi", "tutu", "tyty"),
              c("titi", "tu", "tyty", "tete"),
              c("tktk", "ta"))
```

And I want to build a list (of the matchings) which has a similar structure as the `List1` object, except that the character vectors are replaced by a list of the matching indices of first level elements of `List2`, this for each string of each character vector.

The matching list that I would to obtain with `list1` and `list2` examples is thus :

```
Matchings <- list(list(list(1), list(1,3,4)),
                  list(list(2)),
                  list(list(1), list(), list(1,3)))
```

I've built the following code solution (that works, but too slow) with loops :

```
Matching_list <- lapply(List1, function(x) sapply(x, function(y) return(list())))

for (i in 1:length(List1)) {
  for (j in 1: length(List1[[i]])) {
    Matchings = list()
    for (k in 1: length(List2)) {
      if(any(List1[[i]][j] %in% List2[[k]])) {
        Matchings <- c(Matchings, k)
      }
      if(length(Matchings) != 0) {
        Matching_list[[i]][[j]] <- Matchings
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... but it's definitly too slow for large lists. Thus, I seek for a solution that would make that stuff without loops as far as possible.

Could you help me?

Comment: How large is your data? What does your current loop-solution look like? I doubt that a completely loop-free solution will be possible.

Comment: Hello. My lists have more than 10K vectors of from 1 to up to 20 words. I've just updated my question with the "loop solution" code which is definitily too slow.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
inds <- rep(seq_along(List2), sapply(List2, length))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5
ls <- unlist(List2)
res <- 
relist(sapply(unlist(List1), function(a) as.list(inds[which(ls %in% a)])), skeleton=List1)

all.equal(Matchings, res)
#[1] TRUE
```

Which will give your desired output. I doubt that its possible without, at least, looping over `List1`.

Comment: On a similar note, to (1) avoid `sum(lengths(List1)) * sum(lengths(List2))` comparisons (btw, I guess "`=="` should be faster than `"%in%"` in this case) and, (2) loop over `length(List1)` elements instead of `sum(lengths(List1))`, an approach would be to convert "List2" to a form as `l2 = split(rep(seq_along(List2), lengths(List2)), unlist(List2))` which can, simply, be subset by "List1" (`lapply(List1, function(nms) l2[nms])` plus any more formatting)

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work. I need to check further with a large list and I will come back to say if it's ok or not.

Comment: The code proposed by 989 seems to work. For a true list1 trucated to 100 elements, my loop solution takes 33s versus ~2s for your's. I tried to add "use.names=T" after the "skeleton" argument in order to keep the "toto" names for the sublists of matches as I have in my solution, but I get an error message : Error in relist(sapply(unlist Data_EHPAD_merged_Medicament_field_Seqs), : unused argument (use.names = T). Any idea?